# Why does a superclass reference calling an overridden method appear polymorphic, but not if it takes an overridden member variable？

Tags: java, bytecode

```
package main.java;

public class Demo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        BClass bClass=new BClass("han","男");
        AClass aClass=bClass;
        System.out.println(aClass.getSex());
        System.out.println(aClass.sex);
    }
}
```

The execution result of this class is

```
男
null
```

The results are confusing to me. When the superclass calls the overridden method, the results meet my expectations, but when it calls the overridden variable, the results confuse me.so why does a superclass reference calling an overridden method appear polymorphic, but not if it takes an overridden member variable？Here's the entire code.

```
package main.java;

public class Demo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        BClass bClass=new BClass("han","男");
        AClass aClass=bClass;
        System.out.println(aClass.getSex());
        System.out.println(aClass.sex);
    }
}
```

```
package main.java;

public class AClass {
    private String name;

    public String sex;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

}
```

```
package main.java;

public class BClass extends AClass{

    private String sex;

    public BClass(String name,String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
        super.setName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't allow you to really override a field.

Your `BClass` actually has two fields named `sex`, one from `AClass`, and one from `BClass`. And Java syntax doesn't really help you finding out which one is meant when you write something like `x.sex`. It's as if you had defined two different fields, `sex_a` in `AClass` and `sex_b` in `BClass`, only with the complication that references to both are written like `x.sex`, without a clear hint which of the two is meant here.

In your case:

- Your BClass instance will have its `sex_b` initialized, and the `sex_a` empty (null).
- `aClass.getSex()` always calls the most specific method, based on the instance's runtime class, being `BClass`. So it chooses the method from `BClass`, returning `sex_b`, and thus prints the sex.
- `aClass.sex` accesses one of the two `sex` fields, depending on the variable's compile-time-deducible type, in your case being `AClass`. So it prints the `sex_a` value, being null.

Seasoned Java developers typically do their best to avoid this situation, as it can be very confusing.

If the two fields conceptually have the same meaning, do it as you did with the `name` field, having only one field in the parent class, and have the subclass access it via getters and setters (or by declaring `protected` visibility for the field).

If the two fields have conceptually different meanings (can an object have two different sexes?), use different names.

Answer (score 2):

While you can override a method, you can't override a field in a subclass; you are actually just declaring a field with the same name. To allow the field to also be visible in the child class, you can change its visibility to `protected` or package private (default modifier), if both classes are in the same package. [Demo](https://ideone.com/DpEjtS).

```
public class BClass extends AClass{
 
    public BClass(String name,String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
        super.setName(name);
    }
 
    @Override
    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }
 
    @Override
    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }
 
}
public class AClass {
    protected String name, sex;
 
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
 
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
 
    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }
 
    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the Java specifications, the instance variables are not overridden from a super class by a sub class when it is extended.